# How do I close an open port from the terminal on the Mac?

Tags: macos, port

I opened port #5955 from a java class to comunicate from a client. How do i close this port after I am done? and also which command can show me if port open or closed?

Comment: How did you open that port? It is not clear whether you are talking about opening and closing the ports in the java application or from the firewall.

Answer (score 634):

1. Find out the process ID (PID) which is occupying the port number (e.g., 5955) you would like to free

   ```
   sudo lsof -i :5955
   ```
2. Kill the process which is currently using the port using its PID

   ```
   sudo kill -9 PID
   ```

Comment: Sending -9 should not be the first attempt to kill a process, and it a very bad habit. As I recall, you should first just use `kill PID`(which implies -15), then try -2 and -1. -9 is the last resort only if **every** other options failed to work.

Comment: did kill pID without any flags as suggested by @Meow and this worked for me

Comment: this answer works for me, but what does those numbers (15,2,1,9) mean?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 108):

To find the process try:

```
sudo lsof -i :portNumber
```

Kill the process which is currently using the port using its PID

```
kill PID
```

and then check to see if the port closed. If not, try:

```
kill -9 PID
```

I would only do the following if the previous didnt work

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Just to be safe. Again depending on how you opened the port, this may not matter.

Answer (score 77):

**EDIT**

In 09/2022 this helped me for MacOS Monterey M1 Pro Chip:

`sudo lsof -t -i tcp:yourPortNumber | sudo xargs kill`

In 2018 here is what worked for me using MacOS HighSierra:

`sudo lsof -nPi :yourPortNumber`

then:

`sudo kill -9 yourPIDnumber`

Comment: `lsof -nPi` is slightly better because the port number is actually visible in the output and you get a better feeling of what you are killing.

Comment: Also helpful just to see all listening ports' info: `sudo lsof -nPi | grep LISTEN`

Answer (score 38):

very simple find port 5900:

```
sudo lsof -i :5900
```

then considering 59553 as PID

```
sudo kill 59553
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answers!

Comment: clear and concise solution.

Answer (score 36):

One liner is best

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i:PORT -t) 2> /dev/null
```

Example :
On mac, wanted to clear port 9604. Following command worked like a charm

```
 kill -9 $(lsof -i:9604 -t) 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 35):

However you opened the port, you close it in the same way. For example, if you created a socket, bound it to port 0.0.0.0:5955, and called listen, close that same socket.

You can also just kill the process that has the port open.

If you want to find out what process has a port open, try this:

```
lsof -i :5955
```

If you want to know whether a port is open, you can do the same lsof command (if any process has it open, it's open; otherwise, it's not), or you can just try to connect to it, e.g.:

```
nc localhost 5955
```

If it returns immediately with no output, the port isn't open.

It may be worth mentioning that, technically speaking, it's not a port that's open, but a host:port combination. For example, if you're plugged into a LAN as 10.0.1.2, you could bind a socket to 127.0.0.1:5955, or 10.0.1.2:5955, without either one affecting the other, or you could bind to 0.0.0.0:5955 to handle both at once. You can see all of your computer's IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with the `ifconfig` command.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this first command to kill a process that owns a particular port:

```
sudo netstat -ap | grep :<port_number>
```

For example, say this process holds port ***8000*** TCP, then running the command:

```
sudo netstat -ap | grep :8000
```

will output the line corresponding to the process holding port ***8000***, for example:

```
tcp  0  0 *:8000   *:* LISTEN  4683/procHoldingPort
```

In this case, ***procHoldingPort*** is the name of the process that opened the port, ***4683*** is its pid, and ***8000*** (note that it is TCP) is the port number it holds (which you wish to close).

Then kill the process, following the above example:

```
kill  4683
```

As others mentioned here out, if that doesn't work (you can try using kill with -9 as an argument):

```
kill -9 4683
```

Again, in general, it's better to avoid sending `SIGKILL` (-9) if you can.

Answer (score 8):

Find the process ID using command

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:8080
```

After getting the processId

```
sudo kill -9 processID
```

Then provide your system password.

Answer (score 6):

I use `lsof` combined with `kill`, as mentioned above; but wrote a quick little bash script to automate this process.

With this script, you can simply type `killport 3000` from anywhere, and it will kill all processes running on port `3000`.

https://github.com/xtrasimplicity/killport

Comment: You saved my day. For some reason `lsof` in combination with `kill` didn't  return anything and made my script hang on macOS Sierra. But `killport` works like a charm and is faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have created a function for this purpose.

```
function free_port() {
    if [ -z $1 ] 
    then
        echo no Port given
    else
        PORT=$1;
        PID=$(sudo lsof -i :$PORT) # store the PID, that is using this port 

        if [ -z $PID ] 
        then
            echo port: $PORT is already free.
        else
            sudo kill -9 $PID # kill the process, which frees the port
            echo port: $PORT is now free.
        fi
    fi
}

free_port 80 # you need to change this port number
```

Copy & pasting this block of code in your terminal should free your desired port. Just remember to change the port number in last line.

Answer (score 6):

### Simple One-liner

There is a way more straightforward command today, than the other ones (without Sudo, packages or multiple lines)
To kill port 8080 simply call:

`lsof -ti tcp:8080 | xargs kill`

Answer (score 5):

This seem to work for me. Just change your_port_number into the port number you want to stop.

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:your_port_number | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 3):

try below, assuming running port is `8000`:

```
free-port() { kill "$(lsof -t -i :8000)"; }
```

I found the reference [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/find-and-kill-port-processes-on-a-mac-using-bash-c5e95b9e704e)

Answer (score 1):

When the program that opened the port exits, the port will be closed automatically. If you kill the Java process running this server, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux/macOS:
**Step 1:**

```
sudo lsof -i :5955
```

**Step 2:**
Note the PID (Process ID) value that appears in the printout.
**Step 3:**

```
kill <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

This script to Stop port will help you to stop the port by writing `stop <portnumber>` to kill the running port in the terminal. it is usually handy when I try to start a program and the port is already occupied. It uses the below code.

```
pid=$(lsof -ti tcp:$1)
if [[ $pid ]]; then
  kill -9 $pid
  echo "Congrats!! $1 is stopped."
else
   echo "Sorry nothing running on above port" 
fi
```

https://www.hectane.com/blog/stop-port-in-terminal

Answer (score -3):

1. First find out the Procees id (pid) which has occupied the required port.(e.g 5434)

   ps aux | grep 5434

2.kill that process

```
   kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: Use following command to find port        `sudo lsof -i :5955`