# Loopback CLI created PersistedModel properites not working when model json updated

Tags: express, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, angular-loopback

I've created a model using below command line tool in mac terminal and created model name with PersistedModel.

> > lb model

I've got respective json and js file for model and json structure looks as follows.

```
 {
 "name": "otp",
 "base": "PersistedModel",
 "idInjection": true,
 "options": {
   "validateUpsert": true
 },
"properties": {
   "otpnumber": {
   "type": "string",
   "required": true
 },
 "friends": {
  "type": "string",
  "required": true
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {},
"acls": [],
"methods": {}
}
```

these were generated from command line/terminal.Now I need to add few properties to this model and I edited this model json as follows

```
 {
 "name": "otp",
 "base": "PersistedModel",
 "idInjection": true,
 "options": {
   "validateUpsert": true
 },
"properties": {
   "otpnumber": {
   "type": "string",
   "required": true
 },
 "friends": {
  "type": "string",
  "required": true
  },
 "firstName": {
  "type": "string",
  "required": true
  },
  "city": {
  "type": "string",
  "required": true
  }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {},
"acls": [],
"methods": {}
}
```

After editing json file I restarted my localhost server and I found following error in terminal.

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
at doListen (net.js:1501:7)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:678:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm verb lifecycle Verification@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true 
npm verb lifecycle Verification@1.0.0~start: PATH: 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp bin:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Samples/Verification/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
npm verb lifecycle Verification@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/xxx/Desktop/Samples/Verification
npm info lifecycle Verification@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
npm verb stack Error: Verification@1.0.0 start: `node .`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-
lifecycle/index.js:280:16)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>         (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-    lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
npm verb pkgid Verification@1.0.0
npm verb cwd /Users/xxx/Desktop/Samples/Verification
npm verb Darwin 17.0.0
npm verb argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.0/bin/node"     "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start" "-verbose"
npm verb node v8.9.0
npm verb npm  v5.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Verification@1.0.0 start: `node .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Verification@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely     additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxx/.npm/_logs/2017-11-01T12_14_39_706Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:3000` means that the port 3000 is in use. Try this solution to close it: [How do I close an open port from the terminal on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397175/how-do-i-close-an-open-port-from-the-terminal-on-the-mac)

Once you've closed the port, you should be able to start up the application again.